# How to convert LIST of dates to single CronExpression?

Tags: java, spring, cron

Since I applied for internship I have to resolve this task:
**I need to create a method that turns *list* of dates to single CronExpression.**
Only Java code (no outside frameworks).
Just like this :

```
Input:

    "2022-01-25 T 08:00:00"
    "2022-01-25 T 08:30:00"
    "2022-01-25 T 09:00:00"
    "2022-01-25 T 09:30:00"
    "2022-01-26 T 08:00:00"
    "2022-01-26 T 08:30:00"
    "2022-01-26 T 09:00:00"
    "2022-01-26 T 09:30:00"

Output:
    "0 0/30 8-9 * * *"
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any general (commonly used) way to do that? Or it is not typical task and I have to create that method from the zero?
2. Can you explain me a logic of how I need to do that? Mainly I don't understand how to convert **SEVERAL** dates to one CronExpression.

Comment: `0/30 8-9` means every 30 minutes for the hours of 8 and 9.  I guess that the task is for your code to examine the data and to come up with the pattern

Comment: It is certainly NOT a typical task, which I think is the whole point - they want to see not only your Java knowledge, but also (or rather: especially) they want to see how YOU figure out the logic of how you do that.   We're happy to help by giving our thoughts to clarify (such as what the crontab means), but not to defeat the purpose of the exercise.